# Migrating GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When migrating a project with no organization to a new organization, can we maintain the same billing account, or do we have to set up a new one?

Once the project is migrated, is there anything left to "close out" at the source?  Since there is no organization in the source, there shouldn't be any folders.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same billing account. A billing account can be associated with multiple projects (standalone or part of an Organization).

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate a project that is not associated with an organization into an organization. However, you can't change it back to **No organization** using this process. If you have a project that is associated with your organization and you want to revert it to **No organization**, reach out to your Support representative for assistance. **Note**, you need to set up the billing account again to migrate the projects from no organization, you can use the same billing account. You may check this documentation for reference. [Migrating projects with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#:%7E:text=Handling%20special%20cases-,Migrating%20projects%20with%20no%20organization,-You%20can%20migrate)

> ***Note***: Reverting a project to No organization requires business  justification.

Once the project is migrated there is nothing left to close out at the source. You may check this documentation for reference. [IAM policy inheritance](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#:%7E:text=of%20the%20project.-,IAM%20policy%20inheritance,-Google%20Cloud%20offers)

Comment: so new billing account is not required on the initial migration, only on the migration back to no organization?

Comment: @user994165 yes a new billing account is not required. If you are going back to no organization you need to contact the GCP Support for detailed information.